# which db connection will be used if connection object not provided in query?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$db1 = mysql_connect('host1', 'user', 'user'); 
$db2 = mysql_connect('host2', 'user', 'user', true); 

mysql_select_db('db1', $db1);
mysql_select_db('db2', $db2);


mysql_query("select * from table1");
```

which db connection will be used if connection object not provided in query?

Comment: Why don`t you try it? It`s the last = db2

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: i need two servers to try it though. @aldanux Thanks. i am working on existing project so can't use modern replacement. Thanks

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated - Please use PDO or MySQLi_*

Comment: Existing project or not, it makes no difference.

Comment: for existing project, do you think i should use PDO in 2-3 files. are you NUTTS

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php):

> link_identifier
>
> The MySQL connection. If the link identifier is not specified, **the
> last link opened by mysql_connect() is assumed**. If no such link is
> found, it will try to create one as if mysql_connect() was called with
> no arguments. If no connection is found or established, an E_WARNING
> level error is generated.

So in your case, db2.